# Row Specific Filtering of Dataframe cannot be displayed in Tkinter through a button.But it works on a normal Conditional Statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tkinter

I am a complete noob in Tkinter and I am doing a data based project on Pandas.For a certain part of the code to display specific rows as A table in Tkinter.For the same I got a code from Internet to display a dataframe using a Tkinter window(enclosed down as disp_df function) which uses pandastable library. I had already created a rowview function which displays the chosen rows of the dataframe.
Combining both I created a program with two buttons.It should work such that, the first button displays the chosen rows of the dataframe  and the second button displays the entire dataframe. However it does not work properly.While the second button works properly, the first button only displays a empty table.
To debug I used a conditional statement to do the same instead of the button.Quite weirdly this one works properly.Can someone help me debug the issue.I have organized it in such a way that if the initial function works such that if debug=True is passed into it, the conditional statement part works otherwise,
the button part works. Any help in this regard would help me complete this assignment.

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import *
from pandastable import Table
import random
size=random.randrange(1, 10,1)
cols=[random.randrange(1, 50, 1) for i in range(size)]
df = [random.randrange(1, 50, 1) for i in range(size)]
cols=np.asarray(cols)
#create a random dataframe
df=pd.DataFrame([df],columns=cols) 
display(df)
root = Tk()
def row_view():
        choices = dict(zip(cols.tolist(), [0]*len(cols)))
        row_val=0
        print(choices)
        window1 = Tk()
        window1.geometry("1000x1000")
        window1.title("Modify Entry")
        mod=Frame(window1)
        mod.pack()
        for choice in choices:
            lbl = Label(mod, text=choice)
            lbl.grid(row=row_val,column=0)
            choices[choice]=IntVar()
            chk = Checkbutton(mod,text="",variable=choices[choice])
            chk.deselect()
            chk.grid(row=row_val,column=1,sticky="ew")
            row_val+=1
        window1.mainloop()
        def clicked(e):
            global lst
            result=df[[key for key,val in choices.items() if val.get()==1]]
            disp_df(result)
        btn = Button(mod, text="Submit")
        btn.bind("<Button-1>", clicked)
        btn.grid(row=row_val+3,column=1)
        print([key for key,val in choices.items() if val.get()==0])
        
def initial(debug=False):
    if debug:
         #Mimic a button using if/else
        choice=int(input('Button:'))
        if choice==1:
            row_view()
        elif choice==2:
           disp_df(df)
    else:
        #True Button
        window2=Tk()
        window2.title("Menu") 
        bt1= Button(window2, text="Add_Row",command=row_view)
        bt2= Button(window2, text="Display",command=lambda:disp_df(df))
        bt1.pack()
        bt2.pack()
        window2.mainloop()
def disp_df(df):
    display(df)
    class TestApp(Frame):
            """Basic test frame for the table"""
            def __init__(self, parent=None):
                Frame.__init__(self)
                self.parent = parent
                self.main = self.master
                self.main.title('Table app')
                f = Frame(self.main)
                f.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
                self.table = pt = Table(f, dataframe=df,
                                        showtoolbar=False, showstatusbar=True)
                pt.show()
                return
    
    frame = Tk()
    app=TestApp(frame)
    app.pack()
initial()
#initial(debug=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should only have one `mainloop()` so remove `window.mainloop()` after packing the buttons, and everywhere else You have done it like this, there should be just one `mainloop()`

Comment: @Matiiss I know, you have kinda given me the answer but I would like to know, where in my code if I call mainloop() it will be easy enough for all the windows to execute properly.Please note that I am a complete novice in Tkinter and I am using it for the first time.

Comment: @Matiiss In my understanding, I have commented out all the mainloops and added one mainloop() in the end (have edited the question ) please look for reference. But still the problem persists. Hope someone helps me out.

Comment: the other thing is that You also should keep just one instance of `Tk()`, for additional windows You could use `Toplevel`, so that would be great too, but basically there should be one `Tk()` instance for example `root = Tk()` and then at the end call `root.mainloop()` since plain `mainloop()` is bad practice anyways. And then You "base" everything around this `root`.

Comment: For example `TestApp` is inheriting from a `Frame` so what You usually would do is sth like `app = TestApp(root)` and then `app.pack()` or `.grid` or `.place`

Comment: The immediate fix I could suggest You is that You place `root = Tk()` at the start of the program (after imports), then write `root.withdraw()` and at the end have a `root.mainloop()` (where You now have just `mainloop()` place `root.mainloop()`) and then everywhere where You had `Tk()` place `Toplevel(root)` and don't change anything else, this should work

Comment: @Matiiss Have updated the code, so as to work out the mistake I have done. All works properly except that the disp_df() function which worked great before is not working even if I call directly. Can u check the same. This is weird as it was working properly before. I could say the function is working as I printed test statements inside it and they printed. Please help me for the same. I guess this would be the last bug. Thanks for all the help done already.

Comment: firs thing in the `__init__` would be to do `Frame.__init__(self, parent)` and then do `self.parent = parent`, also considering that `root` is withdrawn it You won't be able to see it there, so maybe You need to create another `Toplevel` and place the frame on that one instead of `root`

Comment: @Matiiss This time, the window is opening but its blank. I am sorry for annoying you, but no one has helped me yet. I have updated the code again. Thanks for ur help.

Comment: oh, it's fine, btw You didn't add the parent to inheriting class. It should be `Frame.__init__(self, parent)`

Comment: @Matiiss Hmm, now it works properly Thanks for ur help. I have been working on this for almost a week. I propose writing a answer. So that someone else might get help. Don't worry I will write it myself with due credits to your comments. Thank You so much once again.

Comment: Honestly You scared me a little because I didn't want to write an answer since I wouldn't really know what to write about, since I just gave a few suggestions.

Comment: @Matiiss, Thanks again I have created a answer for the question. I also completed my entire project for my father's company. He was very happy and pleased. This is my first personal project. Its around 650 lines of code including this snippet. It was all possible because of you. Thanks so much!.

Comment: That is good to hear, glad to help. Btw I would have to mention that it is possible to manage multiple Tk() instances too but it is way easier to just use Toplevel(). Also it is not that it is confusing for python to understand since it really understands nothing and just does what the dev asks for (if the dev can ask so that python (or any other programming language) can easily and precisely understand it, it will execute fine)

Comment: @Matiiss, have added your comment in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

So, first I would thank the person who helped me in the comments of this post. His help was so inevitable in my query. Firstly I understood that there should be only one Tk() and one mainloop in a program as its a kind of infinite loop and having multiple infinite loops in a program is a bit confusing for Python to understand. Then he pointed out there was a method called Toplevel in Tkinter(which I missed in my self-study) for creating multiple windows. So firstly I have to create the root then, withdraw it and at the end have one mainloop. The other windows could be defined as Toplevel(root). The other problem which we discussed on the comments was just a mistake in how the class's constructor was declared was declared so I think it would be irrelavant to the core question(which I directly edited in the question). Here's the changed code for your reference.

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import *
from pandastable import Table
import random
size=random.randrange(1, 10,1)
cols=[random.randrange(1, 50, 1) for i in range(size)]
df = [random.randrange(1, 50, 1) for i in range(size)]
cols=np.asarray(cols)
#create a random dataframe
df=pd.DataFrame([df],columns=cols) 
display(df)
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
def row_view():
        choices = dict(zip(cols.tolist(), [0]*len(cols)))
        row_val=0
        print(choices)
        window1 = Toplevel(root)
        window1.geometry("1000x1000")
        window1.title("Modify Entry")
        mod=Frame(window1)
        mod.pack()
        for choice in choices:
            lbl = Label(mod, text=choice)
            lbl.grid(row=row_val,column=0)
            choices[choice]=IntVar()
            chk = Checkbutton(mod,text="",variable=choices[choice])
            chk.deselect()
            chk.grid(row=row_val,column=1,sticky="ew")
            row_val+=1
        def clicked(e):
            global lst
            result=df[[key for key,val in choices.items() if val.get()==1]]
            disp_df(result)
        btn = Button(mod, text="Submit")
        btn.bind("<Button-1>", clicked)
        btn.grid(row=row_val+3,column=1)
        print([key for key,val in choices.items() if val.get()==0])
        
def initial(debug=False):
    if debug:
         #Mimic a button using if/else
        choice=int(input('Button:'))
        if choice==1:
            row_view()
        elif choice==2:
           disp_df(df)
    else:
        #True Button
        window2=Toplevel(root)
        window2.title("Menu") 
        bt1= Button(window2, text="Add_Row",command=row_view)
        bt2= Button(window2, text="Display",command=lambda:disp_df(df))
        bt1.pack()
        bt2.pack()
def disp_df(df):
    display(df)
    class TestApp(Frame):
            """Basic test frame for the table"""
            def __init__(self, parent=None):
                Frame.__init__(self,parent)
                self.parent = parent
                self.main = self.master
                self.main.title('Table app')
                f = Frame(self.main)
                f.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
                self.table = pt = Table(f, dataframe=df,
                                        showtoolbar=False, showstatusbar=True)
                pt.show()
                return
    
    frame = Toplevel(root)
    app=TestApp(frame)
    app.pack()
initial()
#initial(debug=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Edit:
Note: I would have to mention that it is possible to manage multiple Tk() instances too but it is way easier to just use Toplevel(). Also it is not that it is confusing for python to understand since it really understands nothing and just does what the dev asks for (if the dev can ask so that python (or any other programming language) can easily and precisely understand it, it will execute fine) – Matiiss 4 hours ago
Add a comment